# Swift's UITextView's shouldChangeTextInRange method not being called?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's what I've got so far. Not sure why this method is not being called.

```
// viewDidLoad ->
// textView?.delegate = self

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if text == " " {
        sentenceWordCount += 1
    }

    return true

}
```

Comment: can you show more codes?

Comment: latest for swift:

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool { ....

Answer (score 2):

I was not setting 'textView.delegate = self' in the correct area. It was in viewDidLoad(), but I placed it into viewDidAppear() and it's working.